# React treats Timeline element as null even with a condition check

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, typescript-typings

I am using the react-event-timeline lib (here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-event-timeline)  to create a timeline for one of my pages.

I create a list of events called: events and pass it to the timeline. The timeline consists of two parts the first is the initial event, when the page is created there is a timeline event at the top of each timeline to catch that. The second part is dynamically generated based on the list of events provided by the state of the page.

React throws this timeline error and based on debugging I think the issue is with the structure of the html below where The **&& checks are**:

The error I get is:

**React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed null**.

**The above error occurred in the  component:
    in Timeline (created by TimelineComponent)**

```
<Timeline className={styles.timeline}>
                  {(data) && (<TimelineEvent
                      createdAt={Moment(data.creationDateTime).fromNow()}
                      icon={<ActionIcon variant={'create'} fontSize={18} />}
                      iconStyle={this.bubbleStyles('create').icon}
                      bubbleStyle={this.bubbleStyles('create').bubble}
                      subtitle={this.emptyContainer()}
                      contentStyle={contStyle}
                      title={this.creationTitle(data.user)}/>)}

// ^^^ the creation event
// vvv the dynamic part of the timeline. I map each element in events to a timelineEvent
                  {events && (events.map((event, index) => (
                      <TimelineEvent
                          key={index}
                          createdAt={Moment(event.creationDateTime).fromNow()}
                          icon={event.type && <ActionIcon variant={event.type} fontSize={18} />}
                          iconStyle={event.type && this.bubbleStyles(event.type).icon}
                          bubbleStyle={event.type && this.bubbleStyles(event.type).bubble}
                          subtitle={this.emptyContainer()}
                          contentStyle={contStyle}
                          title={this.titleElement(event, index)}>
                          {this.showInfoBox(event.type) &&
                          (<div className={styles.infoBox}>
                                  <div className={styles.infoBoxBody}>
                                      {this.getInfo(event.type)}
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          )}
                          <div className={styles.commentBox}>
                              {event.comment}
                          </div>
                      </TimelineEvent>
                  )))}
              </Timeline>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null && something` resolves to `null`.

It looks like `<Timeline>` can't accept `null` as its `props.children`. Try to prepare events before rendering `<Timeline>`:

```
let allEvents = [];
if (data) allEvents.push(/*something*/)
if (events) {
  allEvents = allEvents.concat(events.map(/*something*/));
}
...
{allEvents.length > 0 && (
  <Timeline>
    {allEvents.map(event => <TimelineEvent/>)}
  </Timeline>
)}
```

Might be a bug https://github.com/rcdexta/react-event-timeline/blob/master/components/Timeline.js#L8

```
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { orientation }))
```

Comment: This was the approach I ended up using. when I generate the events list I just add the creation event to it and sort them based on creationDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is when the value is null, just return an empty div and when you run it, it will work fine.

I think the solution above will cause performance issue since it looped twice.

I hope it helps.